# Keyboard error in Fedora 20 (virtualbox)

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, keyboard

When I press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key it also presses the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key in the guest machine (Fedora 20). This prevents me from typing `[ ] { } ~ ...` and so forth.

My current workaround is: After I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> once while still holding the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key so the "KeyUp event" for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is done and then I have just <kbd>ALT</kbd> and then I can type the characters mentioned above.

This is however very annoying and I wonder if I can configure some settings to stop this from happening.

- Keyboard layout host machine: Belgian (point)
- Keyboard layout guest machine: Belgian (point)

Update:

I have looked around a bit and found that I can see keyboard events (amongst other things) with the `xev` command.

After pressing the <kbd>ALT</kbd> button while having XEV open the relevant output is the following:

> KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
>       root 0x173, subw 0x0, time 5797730, (219,-103), root:(323,625),
>       state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
>       root 0x173, subw 0x0, time 5797730, (219,-103), root:(323,625),
>       state 0x14, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
>       XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
>       root 0x173, subw 0x0, time 5797819, (219,-103), root:(323,625),
>       state 0x94, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1c00001,
>       root 0x173, subw 0x0, time 5797820, (219,-103), root:(323,625),
>       state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
>       XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False